# Wicked_pdf gem not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, production, wicked-pdf

Im using the gem wicked_pdf and it works in development, but now im trying to generate the pdf in production didnt works.

This is my setup:

***gemfile.rb***

```
 gem 'wicked_pdf'
 gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

***config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb***

```
 if Rails.env.production?
      WickedPdf.config = {
        exe_path: "#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-#{Gem.loaded_specs['wkhtmltopdf-binary'].version}/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
      }
 end
```

***controlller/user_profile_controller.rb***

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "ficha",:template => "user_profile/ficha.html.erb",viewport_size: '1280x1024'
      end 
end
```

I already have my html view in *user_profile/ficha.html.erb*

***config/initializers/mime_types.rb***

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

and this is the log error

```
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /usr/bin/env: ruby: Permission denied
):
```

Comment: This was cross-posted in the WickedPDF issue tracker here: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/667